# How to download files with Slackbot in Python?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to create a Slackbot that can download files (excel, csv) from a channel in Slack. If I am not mistaken, I should retrieve a URL, which then can be used in my code to download the file itself. I tried to check the Slack documentation, but I did not find anything useful there. In addition, I use ngrok in the background.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter #Handles events
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import slack
import requests

env_path = ".env"
load_dotenv(env_path)

# Slack API token and signing secret
SLACK_API_TOKEN = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ["SIGNING_SECRET"]
SLACK_USER_TOKEN = os.environ["USER_OAUTH_TOKEN"]
app = Flask(__name__)

slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(SIGNING_SECRET,'/slack/events',app)
client = slack.WebClient(SLACK_API_TOKEN)

@slack_event_adapter.on("file_shared")
def handle_file_shared(event_data):

    file_id = event_data['event']['file_id']
    print(file_id)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```